# Generalizing a definition of maximum of $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, definition

$\textit{Define the Maximum}$ of $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ by the following: $\max\{x,y\} = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x \geq y \\ y & \text{if } y > x \end{cases}$

How can I generalize this definition so that it applies to any finite collection $\{x_1,...x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

I guess I have to make sure I understand the definition first.

My attempt:
I can choose a starting point $x_n$ and my max would be $x_{n+1}$?

Please help!

Comment: How about $\max\{x,y,z\} = \max\{\{x,y,\},z\}$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on a little more on that? Sorry. I am still trying to understand this definition, if anything.

Comment: Comparing 3 objects in one operation is not possible. Taking the maximum of two, and the maximum of those with the third ought to do the trick, and you can extend this approach to dealing with $n$ objects

Comment: @bounceback Are you elaborating off of JavaMan or generalizing your own?

Comment: @Ryan going off of Javaman's approach

Comment: @bounceback Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to show that $\max$ is associative in the following sense: Define $x\vee y:=\max\{x,y\}$ and observe
$$(x\vee y)\vee z=x\vee(y\vee z).$$

One can show via induction that $x_1\vee x_2\vee\cdots\vee x_n$ is well-defined in the following sense: Any placement of parentheses to make $x_1\vee x_2\vee\cdots\vee x_n$ well-defined has the same value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then define $\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}:=\bigvee_{i=1}^n x_i:=x_1\vee x_2\vee\cdots\vee x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_1,...x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$ be a finite collection. And $m = \displaystyle\max \{x_{k} \, | \, {1\le k \le n}\} = x_{i} \, , \, i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$

We can proove easly : $$\displaystyle\forall p \in\mathbb{N}^{*} \, , \quad m \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \le n^{\frac{1}{p}} m$$

Then : $$\displaystyle m = \lim_{p\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

For general case $\{x_1,...x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ you can extract just strictly positive elements, and if $\{x_1,...x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{*}_{-}$ we have : $\displaystyle\max \{x_{k} \, | \, {1\le k \le n}\} = - \min\{-x_{k} \, | \, {1\le k \le n}\}$

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; however, it wasn't asked to be proved. Just to be generalized for a finite collection. Thanks, though.